# Javascript Array Sort with Year Strings

Tags: sorting

I have an Array like this:

```
1992 - title
1998 - Title
2002 -Title
```

etc..

How can i sort this Array by the Years Descending?

so it will look like:

```
2002 - Title
1998 -Title
1002 - Title
```

I tried sort and reverse, but this doesn't work at all, the array remains nearly unsorted, how can i sort this Array?

I also tried to make this a two dimensional array like Year as Number and Title as String to sort by Number but this didn't work as well, i cannot fix this issue here

thx for help

Answer (score 0):

See if it works:

```
var arr = [
                    [1992, "Title 1992"],
                    [1998, "Title 1998"],
                    [1970, "Title 1970"],
                    [2002, "Title 2002"]
        ];

arr.sort(function (a, b) { return (a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : (a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : 0)); });
console.log(arr.join());
console.log(arr.reverse().join());
```

Comment: This was the closest result to sorted descending or ascending, the Problem here is the fact, the Year isn't a number but a String, gets auto converted to string on Strings Combination with +

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator in the sort method: [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

With judicious choice of the comparison, you can sort the array in reverse order of the first four characters:

```
function dateComparer(a, b) {
    return a.substring(0, 4) < b.substring(0, 4);
}

var a = ["1992 - title", "1998 - Title", "2002 -Title"];

a.sort(dateComparer);
```

If your array is actually quite large, you might want to look into the idea of using a sorting map as described in the documentation I linked to.

Comment: Looks interesting , didn't work in any case, the Year isn't a Number, its a string, tried to convert it with parseFloat, but this didn't affect the result...

Comment: Oops! Should have been substring(0, 4), not substring(0, 3).